# Как правильно поставить ударение

Tags: ударение

Где ставится ударение в слове "`лося`"?

Answer (score 1):

Хотелось бы лОся, да не удалОся (поговорка).

Слово "лось" может относиться к двум акцентным классам А и D. Это означает, что

1) возможно неподвижное ударение во всех формах на основе: лОсь, лОсю, лОся, лОсей, лОсями.

2) в форме мн. числа ударение можно сместить на окончание: лОси, лосЕй, лосЯми.

Answer (score 0):

Да, лОся. Именно такая информация в офоэпическом словаре. А поговорка - отличная запоминалка.